# Analyzing SSL/TLS traffic

Tags: networking, ssl, tls

I want to analyze and record SSL/TLS traffic that comes in and out to/from a certain machine. Specifically I'd like to know how many SSL/TLS connections are there, how many connections use TLSv1.2 and how many use older SSL/TLS versions, and which domains were used during the analysis. I want this analysis to be done on live traffic and in parallel write it to a pcap file. Does anyone know a tool that can do that easily?

Comment: [No](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Sortof.  You can use `ssldump` in conjunction with any ssl keys you control.  This won't help for traffic to domains that you do not have the ssl keys for.  You can see the ssl handshake for all the connections, but that won't answer all of the questions you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a tool that can fit your needs: [SSLAnalyzer](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/tree/master/Examples/SSLAnalyzer) which is part of the [PcapPlusPlus](https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus) suite. This tool records SSL/TLS traffic and collects all kinds of data on it, including what you ask which is hostnames, SSL/TLS versions and number of connections. You can use it the following way:

```
./SSLAnalyzer -i <IP_ADDRESS>
```

PcapPlusPlus is multi-platform so you can compile it on Win32, Linux (mainly tested on Ubuntu as web-site specifies) and Mac OS X (you didn't specify the OS you need).
The output goes something like this:

```
STATS SUMMARY
=============

General stats
--------------------

Sample time:                                           14.761 [Seconds]
Number of SSL packets:                                    201 [Packets]
Rate of SSL packets:                                   11.736 [Packets/sec]
Number of SSL flows:                                       25 [Flows]
Rate of SSL flows:                                      1.460 [Flows/sec]
Total SSL data:                                         89632 [Bytes]
Rate of SSL data:                                    5233.320 [Bytes/sec]
Average packets per flow:                               8.040 [Packets]
Average data per flow:                               3585.280 [Bytes]
Client-hello message:                                      23 [Messages]
Server-hello message:                                      23 [Messages]
Number of SSL flows with successful handshake:             22 [Flows]
Number of SSL flows ended with alert:                       5 [Flows]

SSL/TLS ports count
--------------------

| SSL/TLS ports | Count |
-------------------------
| 443           | 25    |
-------------------------

SSL versions count
--------------------

| SSL record version           | Count |
----------------------------------------
| TLSv1.2                      | 20    |
| TLSv1.0                      |  3    |
----------------------------------------

Client-hello versions count
--------------------

| Client-hello version         | Count |
----------------------------------------
| TLSv1.0                      | 23    |
----------------------------------------

Cipher-suite count
--------------------

| Cipher-suite                                       | Count |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256              | 19    |
| TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256            | 4     |
--------------------------------------------------------------

Server-name count
--------------------

| Hostname                                 | Count |
----------------------------------------------------
| assets-cdn.github.com                    | 9     |
| api.github.com                           | 4     |
| collector.githubapp.com                  | 3     |
| accounts.google.com                      | 2     |
| github.com                               | 2     |
| live.github.com                          | 2     |
| www.gmail.com                            | 1     |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: it seems exactly the tool I was looking for. Thanks for the quick answer!